# Getting Publish Details within MVC Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, asp.net-mvc-5, msbuild-task

I'm working on an MVC site with a team and I'd like to display the last publish timestamp and the name of the user that last publsihed within a comment inside of the _Layout.cshtml page while we're in development.  I'm open to packages or msbuild tasks to achieve this, but I'm not positive on the best direction.  Right now, I'm able to display a last build time in this fashion:

```
<!--
Last Built on: @File.GetCreationTime(ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.Location)
Last Built by: //desired output similar to: jsmith
-->
```

The file ownership of the assembly shows the IISAppPool account.

Comment: The last time what exactly was published? The content in the razor view, some content from the database, the assembly or something else?

Comment: How do you publish your website? is it done through a build server? or a deployment script? or right click on the project and select "Publish" using a publish profile?

Comment: This is a job for a build server. Look into something like TeamCity, Cruise Control, Team Foundation Server, or Visual Studio Online.

Comment: Bonner - Last time the application was published to the QA server.  Pete and Aram - Unfortunately, this employer does not utilize a build server so we're publishing from local to a QA server for testing.  Last place I worked, we used a build server that had this functionality custom built into it.  Is there a way to do something similar with an MSBuild task? String replace a variable in _Layout.cshtml to leave an HTML comment of the username?